# Windows CMD: Echo command without executing it

Tags: windows, cmd

I need this line to be written into .txt file:

> do while (num < 10)

I am trying to do it this way

> echo do while (num < 10) >> 1.txt

But it seems that cmd is just executing the comand and not writting it into file

Answer (score 4):

You may use:

```
echo do while (num ^< 10) >> 1.txt
```

Where **^** escapes characters on cmd. Here it escapes **<** which cmd might confuse with operator for inputiing data from file named **10**.

Comment: Great! Works like a charm. Thanx